# Удаление ?page= из адресной строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, apache

Есть ссылка вида: хост/?page=main. Что прописать в .htaccess, чтобы получилось хост/main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^main/?$ /index.php?page=main [NC,L,QSA]
```

NC - не учитывать регистр букв

L - остановить обработку следующих RewriteRule

QSA - пробрасывать get параметры

Comment: Клёво, спасибо огромнейше! А если ещё и для хост/?page=about, хост/?page=info .. чтобы не прописывать каждый раз правило для каждого запроса?

Comment: можно динамически: `RewriteRule ^(main|about|info)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`. Или вообще все передавать в параметр page 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз. Я сделал как в последнем написали, и как оказалось - это то, что мне надо! Ещё раз, спасибо большущее!